# An interpolation type inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities

Let $u(x),x\in R_+$ be a non-negative decreasing smooth function with compact support $[0,L]$, I want to know the following inequality is true? $a\in (0,1)$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x}u^{1+a}dx \le \epsilon \int_0^\infty |u_x|^2dx+C_\epsilon \int_0^\infty u^{2a}dx,$$ where we need $C_\epsilon$ is independent of $L$!!!

P.S. when the left hand is $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^\beta}u^{1+a}dx$ with $\beta>1$, the inequality is true, I want to consider the case $\beta=1$.

Comment: How can a decreasing function have compact support?

Comment: I think he means that the support of $u$ is assumed to be $[0,L]$, which is compact.

Comment: Apparently he means that $u(x)\ge 0$, for all $x\in\mathbb R_+$ and $u(x)=0$, for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: @user44565: Can you explain how it is proved for $\beta>1$?

Comment: For $\beta > 1$, I believe it is proved via an integration by parts and then Young's inequality.

Comment: Note that our function $u$ is only defined on $[0,\infty)$, so the support must be contained in  $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @smyrlis When $\beta>1$ the LHS less than $u^{1+a}(0)=-\int_0^L (1+a)u^a u^\prime$. Then we get the conclusion  by Young's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false for every $\epsilon > 0$. The family of functions to use is this:
$$
u(x):= \left\{ \begin{aligned} & (L-x)^{\frac1{1-a}}, && 0\leq x \leq L, \\
& 0, && x>L. \end{aligned} \right.
$$
Note that $u\in C^1(\mathbb R_+)$. (To get something smooth, mollify this $u$.)

Note also that, for $0\leq x \leq L$, $$(u'(x))^2 = \frac{1}{1-a} u^{2a}(x) = \frac{1}{1-a}(L-x)^{\frac{2a}{1-a}},$$ so the integrals on the right side are the same, up to a constant depending on $a$. Meanwhile, after an integration by parts, the integral on the left side is
$$
\frac{1+a}{1-a} \int_0^L (L-x)^{\frac{2a}{1-a}} \log(1+x) \, dx,
$$
which is again almost the same, except for the logarithmic factor. But if you make $L$ very large, then most of the contribution of this integral is for $x$ large, and then the log factor is a large weight. So as $L\to \infty$, the left side swamps the right side, regardless of the constant.

Comment: This counterexample is very nice. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am a new user.